# Valid template expansion?

Tags: c++11, template-meta-programming, expansion

I am taking a structure that contains variadic types, extracting them, and passing them
to a native function call.

```
//ValueArray contains a vector of a variant type.

// Pulls out an argument from a ValueArray.
template<typename Arg>
inline Arg
_processParam( ValueArray& args ) {
    Arg arg = static_cast<Arg&>( args[ 0 ] );
    args.erase( 0, true );
    return arg;
}


/// Do the Function call. Args is a variadic template pack.
call( fnPtr, _processParam<Args>( args )... );

/// The call expands to:
(*fnPtr)( params... );
```

The problem however is that the _processParam( args )... expansion is pulling out the args by type in reverse order. For example, a ValueArray of [ 1, 1.4 ] will be pulled out as a double, then and int. Is there a way to pull out the arguments correctly and in a portable way?

Comment: Evaluation of the argument expressions of a function call (separated by `,`s which are not comma-operators) is *unordered*. For some compilers like g++, the order is right-to-left, i.e. the rightmost argument expression is evaluated first. It seems your program has Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: Do most compilers evaluate either right-to-left or left-to-right? If so I could just handle those cases for now. Otherwise is there a way to attach an index with the function call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the `erase` and add an index.  Do not mutate data used in other parameter calculations when making a function call, as the order is undefined (which lets the compiler reorder them for efficiencies sake, or the phase of the miin).

You will need to add one level of indirection to do this easily:

```
template<unsigned...>struct indexes {};

template<unsigned num, unsigned... Is>struct make_indexes:
  make_indexes<num-1, num-1, Is...>{};
template<unsigned...Is>struct make_indexes<0,Is...>:indexes<Is...>{};

template<typename... Args, unsigned...Is>
void do_call(indexes<Is...>, ValArray& arr){
  call( fnPtr, ProcessParam<Args>( arr[Is] )... );
}
```

where `ProcessParam` now takes an element not an array, and use it like:

```
do_call<Args...>( make_indexes<sizeof...(Args)>(), arr );
```

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't figure out how to get the indexes. This looks like some kind of zip operation.

Comment: @DanH. answer improved.  You create a pack of indexes of the same size, then expand them in parrallel.  Note that C++1y will have `index_sequence` that does much of the above boilerplate.

Comment: For functions which don't take any arguments I also needed to specialize the do_call function and use make_indexes<0> in place of indexes<Is...>. Many thanks, once again!

Comment: @DanH. really?  Surprised.  `...` on two empty parameter packs should work?  Maybe the problem is it thinks it cannot deduce `Args...` from `<>`?

Comment: It should have worked. The problem came up again when trying to wrap a member function, returning void, and taking 2 parameters, instead of one this time. It only popped up in these specific cases, because I was missing a single '.' in in indexes<Is...>. With. No. Compiler. Errors.